# When I try to run my expo app, it shows this error

Tags: react-native, expo

The bundling fails. Couldn't find anything on this error. My dependencies in `package.json` file is as below

**package.json**

---

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@clerk/clerk-expo": "^0.20.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.19",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.14",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.25",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.64",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "expo": "^50.0.13",
    "expo-secure-store": "^12.8.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.73.0"
  }
```

**Error**

---

[image: Error log]

Comment: I am just going to ask to be sure, is there json before you "dependencies" value?  or have you just deleted it for the sake of StackOverflow